# Enterprise Zenhub API returns `"message":"missing authentication token in headers"` while trying to access the repo

Tags: api, zenhub

I am trying to fetch data from a particular Enterprise Zenhub repository. Following this doc - https://github.com/ZenHubIO/API#get-the-zenhub-board-data-for-a-repository. The auth token and repo-id are correct but it's returning `"message":"missing authentication token in headers"`. Anyone ran into this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should get the zenhub personalized token to make requests to zenhub api.
All requests to the API need an API token. Generate a token in the API Tokens section of your ZenHub [Dashboard](https://app.zenhub.com/dashboard/tokens) 
or for ZenHub Enterprise https:// < zenhub_enterprise_host > /app/dashboard/tokens